# A consistent Formula Example

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am asked to provide an example of a consistent Formula $\psi(x)$  with one free variable $x$ (meaning that the set {$\psi(x)$} is consistent) but $\forall x\psi(x)$ is not consistent.
I'm at a loss here..

is this a good one?
$\psi(x) = \exists y(x^2=y)$

Comment: Is there any more context? What operation/relation symbols can be used, etc.?

Comment: Your $\forall x \psi (x)$ is clearly consistent. In fact (assuming $^2$ is supposed to be an unary function symbol), $\forall x \psi (x)$ is a *theorem*.

Comment: Hilbert System Style, axioms, tautologies, variables..

Comment: How a formula with free variable is meant to be 'consistent'? I guess, it is equivalent to the consistency of $\exists x \psi(x)$, isn't it?

Comment: @Berci: the definition is the same for any set of formulae: the set is consistent iff you can't prove a contradiction from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you're working in a language with a constant symbol $c$. Then $x \neq c$ is clearly consistent, but $\forall x\  x \neq c$ is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks my good sir :] , my brain has apparently taken a vacation today..